# How bad it is - Inline js calls with external handlers definition VS totally external js

Tags: javascript, inline-code

I run into following code in my project:

html:

```
<input type="button" id="addmore" value="Add more" onclick="add_table(this)"/>
```

js:

```
function add_table(elem){
    var current_id = jQuery("table.t1:last").attr("id");
```

First I thought that this code is wrong and I must rewrite it to external code, i.e.

```
jQuery('#addmore)'.click(function add_table(elem){
    var current_id = jQuery("table.t1:last").attr("id");
```

But then I looked at it again and found that this html is more readable - I see which functions binds to which elements already in html, and I don't need to search it in js.

Of course it not encapsulated inside

```
jQuery(document).ready(
```

so it will not work under some circumstances

So question: how bad this code is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a question re-usability and personal taste. Inline code is more readable for very simple things like your example, but of course you are relying on `add_table()` being a global function - if you have hundreds of elements with different click handlers, you could end up with hundreds of functions/variables polluting the global namespace. And that's bad! :)

In terms of re-usability, I find it better to code in distinct components that abstract functionality and can be called upon whenever needed - all within a defined (non-global) namespace.

```
jQuery('#addmore)'.click(function add_table(elem) {
    var current_id = jQuery("table.t1:last").attr("id");
}
```

The code above gives a good [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) - meaning the semantic information (HTML) is oblivious to the behavioural information (Javascript), which again helps create cleaner, more manageable code.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of your site (and level of traffic) there might be a bandwidth issue. i.e. `onclick="add_table(this)"` adds 24 bytes of data to a download. This could be put in a cached JavaScript page which only gets downloaded once, rather than for each request. If you have lots of pages with extra code in them an you have a *lot* of traffic it may make a noticeable bandwidth difference.